# Remove a particular marker in google map clustering in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using GMUClusterItem in my google map to load items.

I can load the items using the below code (its a sample)

```
  let item = POIItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.6646184, -120.9465773, name: "")           
  clusterManager.add(item)
```

It works fine

But my problem is to remove a particular item.

I tried the below code

```
  let item = POIItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.6646184, -120.9465773), name: "")
  clusterManager.remove(item)
```

But its not working

Is there mistake in that? If so, please help me to remove particular item.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code `clusterManager.remove(item)` does remove the marker from the map, but did you refresh the map? You need to call `clusterManager.cluster()` again to update the map rendering.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.clusterManager.cluster()
}
```

(Using Swift 3)

Answer (score 0):

Create array with POIItem's

```
var markers: [POIItem] = []
```

append POIItem to array before adding to cluster

```
markers.append(item)
```

when you would like to remove a marker from the cluster

```
if let marker = markers.first as? GMUClusterItem { 
   clusterManager.remove(marker)
}
```